# How to make tabbed newlines

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

I need to make my text look like this for a homework assignment, how can I achieve that?

[image: Example Image of Text]

(Sorry if the title or tags don't fit, I don't even know how this is called)

Comment: Perhaps the `tabbing` environment would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this effect, including the bold formatting, using the `description` environment:

```
\begin{description}
\item[Beispiel:]~
    \begin{description}
    \item[ERM:]
    \item
    \item[RM:]
    \item[Mitarbeiter] (\underline{Name}, \ldots)
        \begin{description}
        \item FOREIGN KEY \ldots
        \end{description}
    \item[Projekt] (\underline{Nummer})
    \end{description}
\end{description}
```

[image]

The `~` at the end of the second line provides some content to the first `item`, so that the correct spacing results when you enter the inner `description` environment. Note that it isn't needed in line 7, which includes other text.